# How to configure which notifications are skipped in xfce4-notifyd (Lubuntu 12.10)?

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu, notification, notify-osd

I have accidentally clicked on "hide this notification" / "Do not show this message again" button in OSD notification system in Lubuntu 12.10, namely xfce4-notifyd. The information was about wireless network being connected (I still have notification of being disconnected from WiFi) from network applet.

I can configure style of notification with `xfce4-notifyd-config`, how to configure which notifications are shown and which are not?

Comment: I have found some answer on Ubuntu forum about the same issue for `gnome-power-manager`, but the solution doesn't work for my issue: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1050875

Answer (score 4):

As I disable the vpn notification, I found the solution prompted by [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1050875). Open gconf-editor, expand apps, expand nm-applet, you will see the entry of 'disable-vpn-notifications'. Modify the value to undo it.

Answer (score 2):

I also have Xubuntu, and made the same mistake: clicked the "Do not show this message again" button when the (wired) nework connection notification was shown. I restored it like this:

```
# sudo apt-get install dconf-editor dconf-cli
# dconf-editor
```

- Click ctrl-F and search for "disconnect".
- Click "Next" until directory "org" → "gnome" → "nm-applet" is found.
- Unclick the checkbox next to "disable-connected-notifications".
- Close the dconf-editor window.

Answer (score 0):

*Warning: this answer is speculative because I haven't hidden any notifications myself!*

Run `find ~/ -mmin -10 -type f` replacing `-10` with a more appropriate time to specify how far back `find` should go (from the current time).

Depending on how active you've been, you'll get a list of files modified in the period you specified.

To find which file is modified by changing settings in `xfce4-notifyd-config`, I made a simple change, moving the location of the notification from bottom left to bottom right.

I then ran the `find` command given above. This let me identify `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-notifyd.xml` as the file in which at least some settings of `xfce4-notifyd-config` are stored.

I hope you can find information in that file that may let you undo the "hidden" setting. To comment out stuff in `.xml` files use `<!--` to denote the start of a comment and `-->` for the end. In other words, first back up `xfce4-notifyd.xml` and then edit the original to comment out any line (or content) that seems to be responsible for the "hidden" setting.

As I cautioned at the beginning, this is just a suggestion and not a proven means of reversing the "hidden" setting!

For the record, here's what my `xfce4-notifyd.xml` file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<channel name="xfce4-notifyd" version="1.0">
  <property name="notify-location" type="uint" value="3"/>
  <property name="initial-opacity" type="double" value="0.580000"/>
  <property name="expire-timeout" type="int" value="5"/>
</channel>
```

Comment: No, this file only shows settings for **theme** (i.e. visual style of `xfce4-notifyd` notification).

Comment: Downvoted because this is not the answer, as Jakub Narębski said.